# Will Japan's Interstellar Technologies really call its rocket a "Zero"?

Tags: launch-vehicle, japan, interstellar-technologies

The Space News article [Japan’s Interstellar Technologies goes full throttle toward small orbital rocket](https://spacenews.com/japans-interstellar-technologies-goes-full-throttle-toward-small-orbital-rocket/) says:

> LOGAN, Utah — Japanese startup Interstellar Technologies is developing the main engine for an orbital rocket designed to carry 100 kilograms and slated to conduct its initial test flight in 2020.
>
> “Our goal this year is to complete component testing for the regeneratively cooled main combustion chamber, turbopump and gas generator, and to perform an integrated firing test in early 2019,” Uematsu Chiharu, project manager for Interstellar Technology’s suborbital Momo rocket, told SpaceNews at the Small Satellite Conference here. “We already have all the key technologies.”
>
> Interstellar Technologies is raising money for its orbital rocket, **tentatively called Zero**. Japanese investors have contributed “a few million” dollars to date but the firm will need additional funding to begin commercial service in 2021, said Ken Terakawa, structural engineer, for Interstellar Technologies of Hokkaido, Japan.

Will Japan's Interstellar Technologies really call its rocket a "Zero"? Is this a reference to the [Mitsubishi A6M Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_A6M_Zero)?

[image: Interstellar Technologies "Zero"]

Comment: Their website says their new rocket is indeed called Zero: http://www.istellartech.com/technology_en/zero_en -- it doesn't say that it's named after the A6M but I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I remember some comments several months ago when you didn't see anything wrong with Elon Musk selling flame throwers in California either :P

Comment: "Zero" has meanings besides being the American designation for the Mitsubishi A6M.

Comment: @Hobbes "Zero" was actually the Japanese designation ("Navy Type 0 carrier fighter") -- it was introduced in the imperial year 26**00**. The Allies' reporting name was "Zeke". Per WP: *In Japan, it was unofficially referred to as both Rei-sen and Zero-sen; Japanese pilots most commonly called it Zero-sen, where sen is the first syllable of sentōki, Japanese for "fighter plane".*

Comment: @RussellBorogove so "...slated to conduct its initial test flight in 202**0**." may have some relevance.

Comment: @Antzi can you read the hiragana on the rocket? Any idea of the identity of the cute face above it?

Comment: 'Zero' sounds like a reasonable choice for a prototype / development. This isn't too uncommon, e.g. beta versions of software often have 0.x version numbers.

Comment: HA HA HA, It's more than likely an innocent titling mistake and really who cares if they name a craft after a number that could very well correlate to its version. It's not like they are naming it kamikaze 1. Anyways, the company has only received a few million in investment which is currently peanuts in the space industry especially while appearing to be trying to take on SpaceX which is already delivering payloads. But who knows maybe they have some unspoken secret sauce not dislclosed in the article.

Comment: shouldnt we close this question because it is technically off topic and better suited for like a PR SE.

Comment: @anon the name of a spacecraft or of a rocket which will go to orbit is not off-topic, "technically" or otherwise. "better-suited" is never a valid close reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Interstellar Technologies](http://www.istellartech.com/english) (in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_Technologies)) is a Japanese startup based in Hokkaido Japan. They began as a group of rocketry hobbyists and have a 20 year history.

Their website shows "Codename Zero", so it's logical to conclude that while it is currently using "Zero" there may be a different name once it is ready to launch.

Interstellar's current rocket "MoMo" is a 100 km suborbital rocket currently under testing. MoMo-2 failed after lift-off in June 2018. [According to Phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2018-08-high-speed-cameras-momo-failure-unprecedented.html) the initial hypothesis is a problem with a side thruster, which is evident in the second, slow-speed video below after about `01:00`.

**"Zero" will be "ITAR-free":**

> All major components are designed in house and manufactured locally. The vehicle is ITAR free. Launch pad is located near our factory allowing for short lead time and launch costs under $5M USD.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]